# Things doesn't work

Tags: mesh

[image]Something has screwed up my mesh. Build vertexs and move them doesn't work. I am not able to see the mesh in vertex paint. Parts of the mesh get selected as one part. I have no idea what caused this. See the mesh, my settings and say what i got to do. When i delete vertexs, more vertexs get deleted then selected. Draw colour in vertex paint doesn't work. [image]
[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: the *Snapping* tool is active (magnet icon). It can mess up other vertices when you edit the mesh.